# serial port for SIM7000E needs some sort of initialisation

Tags: initialization, serial-port, pyserial, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to run code to test the connection for a SIM7000E hat plugged into the top of a raspberry pi.

If I run a session with cu or minicom, the first attempt to send an AT command fails, after that it works as expected.

If I run C or python code to check send AT commands to the serial port and read the responses, it will work if it is run after the cu or minicom session, but not if run before. Therefore it appears to cu or minicom session does some sort of initialisation to access the port.

When checking for responses from the serial port, the python code uses.

```
with serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0",9600,timeout=1) as ser:
    if ser.in_waiting:
```

If run without running a cu or minicom session first, then ser.in_waiting is always 0 so the code to read the responses never gets run, which obviously explains why it is failing to get any results from the port.

To get it to work, all I need to do is run either cu or minicom and sent the AT command then exit. After that I can get information from the serial port via my python or C code.

So my question is - what are cu and minicom doing to initialise the serial port so that it can be read?

## The following steps outline my situation

attempt to run my python code to send ATE0 and AT+CPSI? to the serial port and check the responses

- no responses received
  run cu -l /dev/ttyS0 -s 9600 -E`
- type AT and press enter
  -- no visable response
- type `. and press enter (to exit)
  reattempt to run my python code
- it functions as expected and gets the desired results from the AT+CPSI? command, such as
  -- CPSI: LTE CAT-M1,Online,505-01,0x7040,146213899,315,EUTRAN-BAND28,9410,5,5,-6,-70,-47,25

I also attempted using cu and not sending any AT command, just using `. to exit - but that didn't only exit cu, it also exited the ssh shell that I had used to log into the raspberry pi.

### Alternatives

minicom also solves the problem in the same manner as cu
C code also fails or succeeds based on whether or not cu (or minicom) has been run to (presumably) initialise the serial port.

### Found a Solution

I have a shell script that calls the python code.
Adding

```
echo '\n' /dev/ttyS0
```

to the shell script prior to calling the python code results in the python code working.
Does anyone know why this works or if there is a better solution.
Note - the python code appends '\r\n' to the commands it sends to the serial port.

---

A respondent asked for the actual code, so here is python code that doesn't receive a response from the AT commands if something else hasn't accessed the serial port first, but successfully receives responses if the serial port has already been accessed (by minicom, cu, or even echo '\n')

```
import sys
import serial
import time
import os
import re
from datetime import datetime

CMD_LB= b'\r\n'

PORT= "/dev/ttyS0"
BAUD= 9600

ser= serial.Serial( PORT , BAUD , timeout=1 )

def send_line( dat ) :
    ser.write( dat.encode('utf-8') +CMD_LB )

def watch(timeout=10,timeend=2,success=None,failure=None)
    t_start= time.time()
    t_read= None
    reply= list()
    while timeout > (time.time()-t_start) :
        if ser.in_waiting :
            line= ser.readline()
            t_read= time.time()
            if line != CMD_LB :
                line= line.decode('utf-8').strip()
                reply.append('\t'+ line)
                if success and line.startswith(success) :
                    return {"ok":True,"reply":reply,"time":t_read}
                if failure and line.startswith(failure) :
                    return {"ok":False,"reply":reply,"time":t_read}
        else :
            if t_read and timeend > (time.time()- t_read) :
                return {"ok":None,"reply":reply,"time":t_read+timeend}
    return{"ok":None,"reply":reply,"time":timeout}

def AT(cmd='', timeout=10, success="OK", failure="+CME ERROR", vrbse=True) :
    cmd= 'AT'+ cmd
    if vrbse:
        print("--------------", cmd, "--------------")
    send_line(cmd)
    reply= watch(timeout=timeout,success=success,failure=failure)
    if vrbse:
        print(reply["reply"],sep='\n')
        print('')
    return reply
    
AT('E0')
response= AT('+CPSI?')
```

Comment: "*If I run a session with cu or minicom, the first attempt to send an AT command fails, after that it works as expected.*" -- This makes no sense at all. "*If I run C or python code ...*" -- Are we supposed to read your mind as to what this code does or does not do? Post your code. "*... it will work if it is run after the cu or minicom session*" -- Which you previously reported would "*fail*"???

Comment: The python or C code simply sends AT commands to the serial port and checks the responses. But it doesn't receive a response if I don't first access the port some other way (either using cu or minicom and sending AT within that program, or the workaround I found of a shell script using "echo '\n' /dev/ttyS0" .